# How to reorder JSON based on desired rule (not by its name or index)?

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I have a JSON and want it to be reordered into a new JSON.

This is how I get my JSON:

```
function getFormData($form){

   var unindexed_array  = $form.serializeArray();
   var indexed_array    = {};

   $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
       indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
   });

   return indexed_array;
}
```

Let's say the result is like this (JSON.stringify()):

```
var txt_JSON = {"username":"john","email":"john@doe.com","age":"29","created_date":"2020-10-28"}
```

I'd like to reorder it by custom. Something like this:

```
var arr_order = [3,2,0,1];
```

Based on the reorder rule, the JSON should change into like this:

```
var txt_JSON = {"created_date":"2020-10-28","age":"29","username":"john","email":"john@doe.com"}
```

Most of the example here show sorting by name or value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform object to array of key-value pairs using `Object.entries`

Then `.map` the `arr_order` to return the expected order of pairs

And transform the pairs back to object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
var txt_JSON = {
  username: "john",
  email: "john@doe.com",
  age: "29",
  created_date: "2020-10-28",
}
var arr_order = [3, 2, 0, 1]
var txt_JSON_entries = Object.entries(txt_JSON)
var new_txt_JSON = Object.fromEntries(arr_order.map((i) => txt_JSON_entries[i]))

console.log(new_txt_JSON)
```